# What to do with mismatch shape(or size) between data and target to be used in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I downloaded several fMRI datasets, using nilearn to do the job. Somehow, the example in nilearn has same shape (or size or length) data vs target (such as in haxby dataset, 1452 time series vs 1452 labels).

I want to use scikit-learn for another type of classification or transformation using a mismatched dataset (for example: target has less length), but it needs the same length of data and target(x_n_samples = y_n_samples).

Is there any type of preprocessing for  this type of problem in scikit-learn?

Comment: Improved the grammar

Comment: whats the dataset you're trying to model?

Comment: fMRI datasets, as stated above.